# How do I fix (raise ValueError("Duplicate Signature: %r" % signature) when I try to run the parallel_apply function from pandarallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, spyder, valueerror

Hi I am getting a error (raise ValueError("Duplicate Signature: %r" % signature) when I try to run the parallel_apply function from pandarallel.

I am using spyder from Anaconda to run the code, there is no issues with the code, the error appears only whenever I try using the parallel_apply function.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug in Jupyter where the messages from forked processes using libraries like multiprocessing can be duplicated, and they are then rejected, resulting in that exception.

This [patch](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/pull/655/commits/9ac65f998ec1398a4dd206d8d18f3babf9947d7e) fixes it by changing the client messages to be unique for each fork. Note that it's not in jupyter_client yet (as of my writing this), but it's a one-liner so you can probably just apply it to your local install. Once 7.0 is out, it should be included.